# Conditional on empty SelectNodes set

Tags: powershell, xpath

Given XML like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Definitions>
    <Products>
        <Product_Group id="Revit">
            <Product id="RVT2017">
                <RSAccelerator>RSACCELERATOR2017</RSAccelerator>
                <ShortcutPath os="6.0 6.1">C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Autodesk\Revit 2017</ShortcutPath>
                <ShortcutPath os="6.2 6.3 10.0">C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Revit 2017</ShortcutPath>
            </Product>
        </Product_Group>
    </Products>
</Definitions>
```

I want to test for the presence of the OS attribute so I can handle getting the value differently when there are two nodes differentiated by that attribute value vs no attribute at all.

I would have thought this would work, with appropriate values for the two variables.

```
if ($script:pxResources.SelectNodes("//Product[@id='$product']/$resource[@os]")) {
```

However, this is returning true even when no nodes are selected. I can use

```
if ($script:pxResources.SelectNodes("//Product[@id='$product']/$resource[@os]").count -gt 0) {
```

but that seems clumsy. Is there a better way to handle this, or is testing for an empty set the only option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you will always have to test as **[`SelectNodes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes?view=netframework-4.7.2)** will return a **[`System.Xml.XPathNodeList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnodelist?view=netframework-4.7.2)** object, which PowerShell will consider to be true even if it is empty.

Agreed adding some code to test is not pretty but AFAIK it's necessary.

My preferred method is **[`IsNullOrEmpty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=netframework-4.7.2)**:

```
[String]::IsNullOrEmpty(<thing>)

# example
$exp = $script:pxResources.SelectNodes("//Product[@id='$product']/$resource[@os]")
if (-not [String]::IsNullOrEmpty($exp)) {# do something}
```

Comment: I think you mean `[String]::IsNullOrEmpty` instead of `IsNotNullOrEmpty`

Comment: Aha, I didn't know you could just convert the whole XML shebang to text and get nothing back. Good thing to learn!

Answer (score 0):

There's a;so the approach where you don't use XPath:

```
[xml]$xml = @"
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Definitions>
    <Products>
        <Product_Group id="Revit">
            <Product id="RVT2017">
                <RSAccelerator>RSACCELERATOR2017</RSAccelerator>
                <ShortcutPath os="6.0 6.1">C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Autodesk\Revit 2017</ShortcutPath>
                <ShortcutPath os="6.2 6.3 10.0">C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Revit 2017</ShortcutPath>
                <ShortcutPath os="">C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anything\Revit 2017</ShortcutPath>
                <ShortcutPath>C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Something\Revit 2017</ShortcutPath>
            </Product>
        </Product_Group>
    </Products>
</Definitions>
"@

$product  = "RVT2017"
$resource = "ShortcutPath"

($xml.Definitions.Products.Product_Group.Product | Where-Object { $_.id -eq $product }).$resource | ForEach-Object {
    if ($null -eq $_.os) { 
        Write-Host "'os' attribute missing on $_"
    }
    elseif ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.os)) { 
        Write-Host "'os' attribute empty on element $($_.outerXml)"
    }
    else { 
        Write-Host "'os' = $($_.os) on element $($_.outerXml)"
    }
}
```

This will output

```
'os' = 6.0 6.1 on element <ShortcutPath os="6.0 6.1">C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Autodesk\Revit 2017</ShortcutPath>
'os' = 6.2 6.3 10.0 on element <ShortcutPath os="6.2 6.3 10.0">C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Revit 2017</ShortcutPath>
'os' attribute empty on element <ShortcutPath os="">C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anything\Revit 2017</ShortcutPath>
'os' attribute missing on C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Something\Revit 2017
```